# какую модель использовать для предсказания последовательности цифр в массиве

Tags: python, tensorflow

У меня есть массив в котором хранятся цифры к примеру - [3,45,1,123 и т.д.] Я хочу что бы модель могла на основе этого массива сделать предсказание своего по типу на выходе получить - [3,44,2,1 и т.д.]. Какую модель выбрать, сразу скажу я пробовал LSTM, но у меня не получалось.

Вот мой код, он начинает запускать первую эпоху и выдаёт ошибку:

```
from music21 import converter, instrument, note, chord
import tensorflow as tf
from scipy.interpolate import UnivariateSpline
from tensorflow import keras

notes = []
file = "C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\titanic_guitar.mid"

# Получаем все ноты и аккорды из файла
midi = converter.parse(file)
parts = instrument.partitionByInstrument(midi)


if parts:
    notes_to_parse = parts.parts[0].recurse()
else:
    notes_to_parse = midi.flat.notes
for element in notes_to_parse:
    if isinstance(element, note.Note):
        # Добавляем "ноты, типа ля2-до3"
        notes.append(str(element.pitch))
    elif isinstance(element, chord.Chord):
        # Добавляем аккорды
        notes.append('.'.join(str(n) for n in element.pitches))

print(notes)
note_to_int = {note: number for number, note in enumerate(sorted(set(notes)))}
for i in range(len(notes)):
    notes[i] = note_to_int.get(notes[i])
print(notes)
model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Dense(128, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax),
    tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(1,)),
])
x_train = notes
y_train = notes
model.compile(optimizer=tf.optimizers.Adam(),
            loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
            metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=5)
```

Вот ошибка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Тебе нужна модель Sequential, LSTM это слой, который можно использовать в твоей модели

Comment: Есть рабочие примеры, а то доки у меня не работают?

Comment: "пробовал LSTM, но у меня не получалось" - а где ваш код? И что значит "не получалось"? Не было никакого предсказания? Или было предсказание, но вы его сочли не качественным? А как вы определили, что предсказание не качественное? Вопросы, вопросы.

Comment: Код самый обычный из доков, у меня ругается на строчку **kwargs и первый аргумент units (мол он пустой)

Comment: Без кода это разговор ни о чём. Не хотите вставлять код в вопрос - дайте на него ссылку, где вы его взяли вообще. Но так то без кода и данных вопросы просто закрывают, потому что это просто гадание и сотрясение воздуха, если этого всего нет.

Comment: И вообще, если нет никакой метрики, то "предсказывать" можно как угодно - можно просто рандомом из какого-то диапазона, а можно брать рандомом смещение в ваших данных и брать цифру оттуда. Например.

Comment: я исправил, можете посмотреть. Это если что чисто мой код.

Comment: Что-то я не вижу слоя `LSTM` тут. Обычные `Dense` слои. Посмотрите какой-нибудь пример именно с `LSTM` и попробуйте его адаптировать под себя.

Comment: я нашёл другое решение и теперь проблема в скрытом слое вот ссылка на вопрос - https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1460378/%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b5-sequential